# C# using multidimensional arrays to create chess board, cant figure out why it only prints in 1 column

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] table = new int[8,8];
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                if ((i + j) % 2 == 0)
                {
                    table[i,j] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    table[i,j] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(table[i,j] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Console.Write**Line**...

Comment: thank you so much... hero of the day

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Console.Write(table[i, j] + " ");` instead of `Console.WriteLine(table[i,j] + " ");`

and thus your code would look like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(table[i, j] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Console.WriteLine` into `Console.Write`.

```
Console.Write(table[i,j] + " ");
```